# How to replace special characters on this.state component on React

Tags: reactjs, replace, properties, state, typeerror

I have fetched api with special characterssuch as ", [, and " but want to remove those special characters with the following code, unfortunately  error is :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

{this.state.apiData.description.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')}

Can someone help me to figure out how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Your error TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined is saying this.state.apiData.description doesn't exist.. specifically the description part. I would console.log(this.state, this.state.apiData, this.state.apiData.description) and let us know what you get....

My guess is, this.state.apiData is probably not what you think it is, or empty.

Comment: Probably because the fetch hasn't finished yet

Comment: Console.log(this.state.apiData.description) is fetching some data like this: "["Singapore is city of endless sights and activities to be had. Let the fun come to you in a full day of excitement and exploration on the Captain Explorer Dukw Tour. ","","The day begins with a ride in an authentic, revamped Vietnam War era vehicle.]. The error comes in when I wanted to replace the special characters using the above code. Thanks

Comment: Yes, as stated above what you THINK is this.state.apiData.description and what actually is there when you run your .replace method are different. You need to console.log this stuff directly before the .replace..

You probably need to create a Promise and .then() your .replace.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to steer you in the direction that you should never mutate your state directly as React's components internal state engine is immutable. Instead do this:

`let state = Object.assign({}, this.state)
 state.apiData.description = value
 this.setState(state)`

With that said, you could probably do something like this:

`let state = Object.assign({}, this.state)
 state.apiData.description = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
 this.setState(state)`

I hope this helps you :)